# Write some logic inside a .snippet file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, code-snippets

I am just curious if it is possible to write some logic inside a .snippet file or is there any work around to do something like that?

For example: Read an xml file and based on that generate the snippet.

Thanks in advance,
Kasun

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to move to a Visual Studio Add-in for this.  (if you are using VS 2010 or lower, you could use a macro,  but macros are not supported by VS 2012, so prefer an add in).

Comment: Thanks.!! This lead me to a whole lot of interesting topics like add-ins, vspackages, macros.

Comment: This is kind of related and will be useful:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/dc4534a6-915e-48d8-b380-be592fd06180

Comment: Hi again, Will it be possible to execute a macro inside from a snippet. Eg: type some snippet shortcut as usual and hit tab will insert a code block which is generated from a macro by reading some file depending on some logic?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that, but you can bind a keyboard shortcut to a macro in Tools | Options | Keyboard.

Comment: Thank you I am going to do it with a Add-in.